# python union of 2 nested lists with index

Tags: python, dataset, list, nested, union

I want to get the union of 2 nested lists plus an index to the common values.

I have two lists like `A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and `B = [[1,2,3,4],[3,3,5,7]]` but the length of each list is about 100 000. To A belongs an index vector with `len(A)`: `I = [2,3,4]`

What I want is to find all sublists in B where the first 3 elements are equal to a sublist in A. In this example I want to get `B[0]` returned (`[1,2,3,4]`) because its first three elements are equal to `A[0]`. In addition, I also want the index to `A[0]` in this example, that is `I[0]`.

I tried different things, but nothing worked so far :(

First I tried this:

```
Common = []

for i in range(len(B)):

   if B[i][:3] in A:

      id = [I[x] for x,y in enumerate(A) if y == B[i][:3]][0]
         ctdCommon.append([int(id)] + B[i])
```

But that takes ages, or never finishes

Then I transformed `A` and `B` into sets and took the union from both, which was very quick, but then I don't know how to get the corresponding indices

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an auxiliary dict (work is `O(len(A)`) -- assuming the first three items of a sublist in A uniquely identify it (otherwise you need a dict of lists):

```
aud = dict((tuple(a[:3]), i) for i, a in enumerate(A))
```

Use said dict to loop once on B (work is `O(len(B))`) to get B sublists and A indices:

```
result = [(b, aud[tuple(b[:3])]) for b in B if tuple(b[:3]) in aud]
```

Comment: Well done for working out enough of what's being asked to produce an answer. My brain hurts trying to understand what it is he wants.